# Spark Dataframe Combine 2 Columns into Single Column, with Additional Identifying Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to split and then combine 2 DataFrame columns into 1, with another column identifying which column it originated from. Here is the code to generate the sample DF

```
val data = Seq(("1", "in1,in2,in3", null), ("2","in4,in5","ex1,ex2,ex3"), ("3", null, "ex4,ex5"), ("4", null, null))

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("id", "include", "exclude")
```

This is the sample DF

```
+---+-----------+-----------+
| id|    include|    exclude|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|  1|in1,in2,in3|       null|
|  2|    in4,in5|ex1,ex2,ex3|
|  3|       null|    ex4,ex5|
|  4|       null|       null|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```

which I'm trying to transform into

```
+---+----+---+
| id|type|col|
+---+----+---+
|  1|incl|in1|
|  1|incl|in2|
|  1|incl|in3|
|  2|incl|in4|
|  2|incl|in5|
|  2|excl|ex1|
|  2|excl|ex2|
|  2|excl|ex3|
|  3|excl|ex4|
|  3|excl|ex5|
+---+----+---+
```

EDIT: Should mention that the data inside each of the cells in the example DF is just for visualization, and doesn't need to have the form in1,ex1, etc.

I can get it to work with union, as so:

```
df.select($"id", lit("incl").as("type"), explode(split(col("include"), ",")))
.union(
    df.select($"id", lit("excl").as("type"), explode(split(col("exclude"), ",")))
)
```

but I was wondering if this was possible to do without using union.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I am thinking off is, better club both the include and exclude columns and then apply explode function. Then fetch only the column which doesn't have nulls. Finally a case statement.

This might be a long process.

With cte as ( select id, include+exclude as outputcol from SQL),
Ctes as (select id,explode(split(col("outputcol"), ",")) as finalcol from cte)
Select id, case when finalcol like 'in%' then 'incl' else 'excl' end as type, finalcol from Ctes
Where finalcol is not null

Comment: But this would fail if there were duplicates in the include/exclude columns right?